# Asynchronous Client/Server pattern in Python ZeroMQ

Tags: python, zeromq

I have 3 programs written in Python, which need to be connected. 2 programs X and Y gather some information, which are sent by them to program Z. Program Z analyzes the data and send to program X and Y some decisions. Number of programs similar to X and Y will be expanded in the future. Initially I used named pipe to allow communication from X, Y to Z. But as you can see, I need bidirectional relation. My boss told me to use ZeroMQ. I  have just found pattern for my use case, which is called Asynchronous Client/Server. Please see code from ZMQ book (http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all) below.

The problem is my boss does not want to use any threads, forks etc. I moved client and server tasks to separate programs, but I am not sure what to do with ServerWorker class. Can this be somehow used without threads? Also, I am wondering, how to establish optimal workers amount.

```
import zmq
import sys
import threading
import time
from random import randint, random

__author__ = "Felipe Cruz <felipecruz@loogica.net>"
__license__ = "MIT/X11"

def tprint(msg):
    """like print, but won't get newlines confused with multiple threads"""
    sys.stdout.write(msg + '\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()

class ClientTask(threading.Thread):
    """ClientTask"""
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)

    def run(self):
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        identity = u'worker-%d' % self.id
        socket.identity = identity.encode('ascii')
        socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5570')
        print('Client %s started' % (identity))
        poll = zmq.Poller()
        poll.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
        reqs = 0
        while True:
            reqs = reqs + 1
            print('Req #%d sent..' % (reqs))
            socket.send_string(u'request #%d' % (reqs))
            for i in range(5):
                sockets = dict(poll.poll(1000))
                if socket in sockets:
                    msg = socket.recv()
                    tprint('Client %s received: %s' % (identity, msg))

        socket.close()
        context.term()

class ServerTask(threading.Thread):
    """ServerTask"""
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)

    def run(self):
        context = zmq.Context()
        frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
        frontend.bind('tcp://*:5570')

        backend = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        backend.bind('inproc://backend')

        workers = []
        for i in range(5):
            worker = ServerWorker(context)
            worker.start()
            workers.append(worker)

        poll = zmq.Poller()
        poll.register(frontend, zmq.POLLIN)
        poll.register(backend,  zmq.POLLIN)

        while True:
            sockets = dict(poll.poll())
            if frontend in sockets:
                ident, msg = frontend.recv_multipart()
                tprint('Server received %s id %s' % (msg, ident))
                backend.send_multipart([ident, msg])
            if backend in sockets:
                ident, msg = backend.recv_multipart()
                tprint('Sending to frontend %s id %s' % (msg, ident))
                frontend.send_multipart([ident, msg])

        frontend.close()
        backend.close()
        context.term()

class ServerWorker(threading.Thread):
    """ServerWorker"""
    def __init__(self, context):
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)
        self.context = context

    def run(self):
        worker = self.context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        worker.connect('inproc://backend')
        tprint('Worker started')
        while True:
            ident, msg = worker.recv_multipart()
            tprint('Worker received %s from %s' % (msg, ident))
            replies = randint(0,4)
            for i in range(replies):
                time.sleep(1. / (randint(1,10)))
                worker.send_multipart([ident, msg])

        worker.close()

def main():
    """main function"""
    server = ServerTask()
    server.start()
    for i in range(3):
        client = ClientTask(i)
        client.start()

    server.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you grabbed the code from here: [Asynchronous Client/Server Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all#The-Asynchronous-Client-Server-Pattern)

Pay close attention to the images that show you the model this code is targeted to.  In particular, look at "Figure 38 - Detail of Asynchronous Server".  The `ServerWorker` class is spinning up 5 "Worker" nodes.  In the code, those nodes are threads, but you could make them completely separate programs.  In that case, your server program (probably) wouldn't be responsible for spinning them up, they'd spin up separately and just communicate to your server that they are ready to receive work.

You'll see this often in ZMQ examples, a multi-node topology mimicked in threads in a single executable.  It's just to make reading the whole thing easy, it's not always intended to be used that way.

For your particular case, it could make sense to have the workers be threads or to break them out into separate programs... but if it's a business requirement from your boss, then just break them out into separate programs.

Of course, to answer your second question, there's no way to know how many workers would be optimal without understanding the work load they'll be performing and how quickly they'll need to respond... your goal is to have the worker complete the work faster than new work is received.  There's a fair chance, in many cases, that that can be accomplished with a single worker.  If so, you can have your server itself be the worker, and just skip the entire "worker tier" of the architecture.  You should start there, for the sake of simplicity, and just do some load testing to see if it will actually cope with your workload effectively.  If not, get a sense of how long it takes to complete a task, and how quickly tasks are coming in.  Let's say a worker can complete a task in 15 seconds.  That's 4 tasks a minute.  If tasks are coming in 5 tasks a minute, you need 2 workers, and you'll have a little headroom to grow.  If things are wildly variable, then you'll have to make a decision about resources vs. reliability.

Before you get too much farther down the trail, make sure you read Chapter 4, Reliable Request/Reply Patterns, it will provide some insight for handling exceptions, and might give you a better pattern to follow.